# Ubuntu Wifi Problems (No adapter found)

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, iwlwifi

So I just installed [minimal Ubuntu 18.04](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2018/07/09/minimal-ubuntu-released) on a [Lenovo Legion Y720](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/legion-laptops/legion-y-series/Legion-Y720/p/88GMY700794) to start using it as a daily driver, but WiFi fails to connect to the Internet despite having enabled Wireless LAN in BIOS/Setup.

`lspci`:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265/8275 (rev 78)
```

`lshw -C network`: Both of the interfaces don't show the DISABLED notifications.

On the actually Ubuntu wifi settings it says unavailable under the word wifi and No wifi adapter found.

The firmware is loading correctly and I am currently out of ideas.

Thank you

Comment: Wireless LAN is enabled in bios and my laptop is a Lenovo Legion Y720

Comment: isn't it smth like that [https://askubuntu.com/questions/893384/wifi-doesnt-work-on-fresh-ubuntu-16-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893384/wifi-doesnt-work-on-fresh-ubuntu-16-04)?

Answer (score 4):

run this on terminal:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf <<< "blacklist ideapad_laptop"
```

and reboot. This should unblock your Wi-Fi.

Comment: YOUR AN AMAZING HUMAN BEING

Comment: This looks like an exact duplicate of [Pilot6's answer on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/893442/816190). In my opinion you should atleast cite the source and give Pilot6 credits.

Answer (score -1):

I just restart my system and run in recovery mode and now my wifi is working.

Comment: And does it still work whan you boot it in normal mode again?